# ¿De que manera puedo ocultar un registro, sin eliminar en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

tengo una tabla en donde necesito eliminar el dato, pero me pidieron que no elimine el dato, si no que lo oculte y este mismo siga en la base de datos. Esto con la finalidad de poder acceder al dato en un futuro en la BD. Estoy aprendiendo Angular, estaba viendo que existe algo que se llama Manejo de Estado y se hace con una libreria llamada NGXS o me encuentro equivocado?, les agradecería mucho si me pudiesen ayudar o guiar de como realizar. ¡Gracias!

**mi Clase listar.component.ts**

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Causa} from '../../../models/causa';
import {CausaService} from '../../../services/causa.service';
import {NgbModal, NgbModalRef} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listar',
  templateUrl: './listar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listar.component.scss']
})
export class ListarComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('modalAgregar', {static: false}) modalAgregar: ElementRef;
  causas: Observable<Causa[]>;
  selectedCausa: Causa;
  modal: NgbModalRef;

  constructor(private causaService: CausaService,
              private modalService: NgbModal,
              private toastr: ToastrService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cargarCausas();
  }

  cargarCausas() {
    this.causas = this.causaService.listar();
  }

  abrirModal() {
    this.modal = this.modalService.open(this.modalAgregar);
  }

  cerrarModal($event) {
    if ($event) {
      this.cargarCausas();
      this.modal.close();
    }
  }

  editar(causa: Causa) {
    this.selectedCausa = Object.assign({}, causa);
    this.abrirModal()
  }

  eliminar(causa: Causa) {
    this.causaService.eliminar(causa).subscribe(data => {
      this.toastr.show('Se elimino correctamente');
      this.cargarCausas();
    });
  }

  agregar() {
    this.selectedCausa = null;
    this.abrirModal();
  }
}
```

**mi clase listar.component.html**

````
  <ng-container *ngIf="$causas && $causas.length > 0">

<section class="intro">
  <div class="gradient-custom-2 h-100">
    <div class="mask d-flex align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark float-right"  (click)="agregar()">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"> agregar</i> <br>
              </button>


    <table class="table table table-bordered mb-0">
      <thead>
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Acciones</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <!-- Lo que hace async pipe es subscribirse al Observable causas y retornar el último valor
       emitido, en este caso la lista de causas devuelta por el servidor.-->

      <tr *ngFor="let causa of causas | async"> <!-- El beneficio de usar async pipe es que una vez que el Observable deja de utilizarse, este lo destruye de forma automática. -->
        <!-- Con esto, por cada una de las causas en la lista de $causas, se repite la etiqueta ,
     permitiendo visualizar la información de cada una de ellas mediante "string interpolation"
     con el uso de llaves y el nombre del atributo que se quiere mostrar.-->
        <td>{{causa.id}}</td>
        <td>{{causa.nombre}}</td>
        <td>{{causa.fechaCreacion}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark mr-1" (click)="editar(causa)">
            <i class="fas fa-edit">  editar</i>
          </button>
          <button type="button" onclick=" return confirm('Esta seguro de eliminar?')"  class="btn btn-sm btn-dark mr-1"
                  (click)="eliminar(causa)">
            <i class="fas fa-trash">  Eliminar</i>
          </button>
        </td>
       </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #modalAgregar>

    <div class="modal-content">
      <app-agregar [causa]="selectedCausa" (cerrarModal)="cerrarModal($event)"></app-agregar>
    </div>
  </ng-template>```
````

Comment: El problema que planteas es del  lado del backend no de Angular. En el front puedes eliminarlo, pero al recargar la página aparecerá de nuevo.

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer seria en la BD, agregar un campo **status** donde estatus sera una bandera lógica con **1 - Si el registro se encuentra activo** y **0 - Si el registro se encuentra inactivo o eliminado lógicamente**, en ves de eliminar el registro haces un **update** a la bandera con 0, en tu consulta agregarías un **where** para obtener solo los activos, esa es una manera sencilla y viable.

Comment: Lo que quieres es ocultar una de las causas?